# How to return a channel

Tags: go, rabbitmq, channel

I'm creating a worker to consume messages from a RabitMQ queue. To achieve that, I created the following file named `queue.go`

```golang
    package ExternalServices

    import (
        "../domain"
        "encoding/json"
        "github.com/streadway/amqp"
        "os"
    )

    const (
        catalogQueue = "catalog-queue"
    )

    func EnqueueMessageCatalog(catalog *domain.Catalog) error {
        marshal, err := json.Marshal(*catalog)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        jsonVal := string(marshal)
        err = enqueue(catalogQueue, jsonVal)
        return err
    }

    func DequeueMessageCatalog() ([]domain.Catalog, error) {
        msgs, err := dequeue(catalogQueue)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        allCatalogs := make([]domain.Catalog, len(msgs))
        for _, currMsg := range msgs {
            var currCatalog domain.Catalog
            err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(currMsg), &currCatalog)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
        }

        return allCatalogs, nil
    }

    func openConnection() (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, error) {
        conn, err := amqp.Dial(os.Getenv("RabbitMQConStr"))
        if err != nil {
            return nil, nil, err
        }

        ch, err := conn.Channel()
        if err != nil {
            conn.Close()
            return nil, nil, err
        }
        return conn, ch, nil
    }

    func ensureQueueExists(queueName string, ch *amqp.Channel) (amqp.Queue, error) {
        q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
            queueName, // name
            false,     // durable
            false,     // delete when unused
            false,     // exclusive
            false,     // no-wait
            nil,       // arguments
        )

        return q, err
    }

    func enqueue(queueName string, message string) error {
        con, ch, err := openConnection()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        defer con.Close()
        defer ch.Close()

        q, err := ensureQueueExists(queueName, ch)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        err = ch.Publish(
            "",     // exchange
            q.Name, // routing key
            false,  // mandatory
            false,  // immediate
            amqp.Publishing{
                ContentType: "application/json",
                Body:        []byte(message),
            })
        return err
    }

    func dequeue(queueName string) ([]string, error) {
        con, ch, err := openConnection()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        defer con.Close()
        defer ch.Close()

        q, err := ensureQueueExists(queueName, ch)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        msgs, err := ch.Consume(
            q.Name, // queue
            "",     // consumer
            true,   // auto-ack
            false,  // exclusive
            false,  // no-local
            false,  // no-wait
            nil,    // args
        )

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        jsons := make([]string, len(msgs))
        i := 0
        for currMsg:= range msgs {
            jsons[i] = string(currMsg.Body)
            i += 1
        }

        return jsons, nil
    }
```

However, I got a bit confused at the `dequeue` function. I want my worker to be notified every time a messages arrives at my queue, so I guess the proper way to do so is to create a string chan to my worker, since I don't want to expose the message channel returned by `Consume` to it.

This is my worker so far.

```golang
package worker

import (
    "../external-services"
    "log"
)

func StartWorker() {
    go func() {
        messages, err := ExternalServices.DequeueMessageCatalog();
        if err != nil {
            // todo log
        }

        for d := range messages {
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d)
        }

    }()
}
```

1. How can I modify my `dequeue` function so it returns a string chan?
2. After modifying this method to return the string chan, do the lines `defer con.Close()` and `defer ch.Close()` need to be deleted from this method?

It's my first project in GoLang so anything you think can increase the quality of the code will be much appreciated :-D

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this:

```
msgs, err := ch.Consume(...)

/* handle error */

stringCh := make(chan string)
done := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    defer con.Close()
    defer ch.Close()
    defer close(stringCh)
    for {
        select {
        case currMsg := <-msgs:
            stringCh <- string(currMsg.Body)
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}()
return stringCh, done
```

This is only a sketchy example. Basic idea is spawn another goroutine listen to the message chan returned by Consume. Other details like how to graceful shutdown, dequeue interface,... depend on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I think I missed the go routine creation.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @YSTai response, I realised I miss the go routine creation. This is how my code end up.

`worker.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "../domain"
    "../externalservices"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

/*
StartWorker initializes a program that will wait for messages enqueued and process them
*/
func StartWorker() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        catalogReceived := make(chan domain.Catalog)
        defer close(catalogReceived)
        for true {

            go func() {
                externalservices.DequeueMessageCatalog(catalogReceived)

                catalog := <-catalogReceived
                website := domain.Website{
                    Name: strings.ToUpper(catalog.Name),
                    Zip:  catalog.Zip}
                externalservices.InsertWebSite(&website)
            }()
        }

    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages")
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    StartWorker()
}
```

`queue.go`

```golang
package externalservices

import (
    "../domain"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    "os"
)

const (
    catalogQueue = "catalog-queue"
)

func EnqueueMessageCatalog(catalog *domain.Catalog) error {
    marshal, err := json.Marshal(*catalog)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    jsonVal := string(marshal)
    err = enqueue(catalogQueue, jsonVal)
    return err
}

// DequeueMessageCatalog is nice
func DequeueMessageCatalog(messageChannel chan domain.Catalog) {

    message := make(chan []byte)
    defer close(message)

    for true {
        go func() {
            dequeue(catalogQueue, message)
        }()

        currCatalog := domain.Catalog{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(<-message), &currCatalog)
        messageChannel <- currCatalog
    }
}

func openConnection() (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, error) {
    connString := os.Getenv("RabbitMQConStr")
    conn, err := amqp.Dial(connString)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        conn.Close()
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    return conn, ch, nil
}

func ensureQueueExists(queueName string, ch *amqp.Channel) (amqp.Queue, error) {
    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        queueName, // name
        false,     // durable
        false,     // delete when unused
        false,     // exclusive
        false,     // no-wait
        nil,       // arguments
    )

    return q, err
}

func enqueue(queueName string, message string) error {
    con, ch, err := openConnection()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer con.Close()
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ensureQueueExists(queueName, ch)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = ch.Publish(
        "",     // exchange
        q.Name, // routing key
        false,  // mandatory
        false,  // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            ContentType: "application/json",
            Body:        []byte(message),
        })
    return err
}

func dequeue(queueName string, message chan []byte) error {
    con, ch, err := openConnection()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer con.Close()
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ensureQueueExists(queueName, ch)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        true,   // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        true,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for currMsg := range msgs {
        message <- currMsg.Body
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: i am not sure I fully understand, but using `for true` to create go routine will quickly OOM.